# How do I pull a specified number of items from NSMutableArray at a given index?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do I pull a specified number of items from NSMutableArray at a given index ?

given NSMutableArray *nsmarrRow;  1000 items

I want to get 20 elements starting at index = 10 ?

```
[nsmarrRow objectAtIndex: 10]; this pull 1 item at this index.
```

Do I have to use a for loop or is there a method in the NSMutableArray class?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[nsmarrRow subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(10, 20)]`

Answer (score 1):

There is this method

```
- (NSArray *)subarrayWithRange:(NSRange)range
```

defined on [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray) which is the super class of [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You should take the time to get used to reading the api and it will make research a lot easier it's just tricky getting your head around how each different language is documented.